# After renaming my mac homefolder, I'm getting the follow error when trying to run: ddev start

Tags: ddev

I had a requirement to rename my mac homefolder, however now when I try to run:
**ddev start**
I'm getting the following error (which is pointing to the older homefolder name gregmercer):

```
~/Desktop/ddev/locals/gsb-3/public-website (develop) $ ddev start
Starting gsb-d8...
Using custom nginx configuration in /Users/gmercer/Desktop/ddev/locals/gsb-3/public-website/.ddev/nginx_full/nginx-site.conf
Custom configuration takes effect when container is created,
usually on start, use 'ddev restart' if you're not seeing it take effect.
Failed to open /Users/gregmercer/Library/Application Support/mkcert: open /Users/gregmercer/Library/Application Support/mkcert: no such file or directory
```

I've tried upgrading ddev, but that didn't seem to help.
I've run mkcert -install, and run mkcert -CAROOT. The last command seems to show the correct path to my newly named homefolder gmercer

```
~/Desktop/ddev/locals/gsb-3/public-website (develop) $ mkcert -CAROOT
/Users/gmercer/Library/Application Support/mkcert
```

At this point I'm not sure what to try. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mkcert CA has been orphaned.

Please try `mkcert -uninstall` and then `mkcert -install`

Then edit or remove the existing `mkcert_caroot` in your ~/.ddev/global_config.yaml

Comment: That seems to have gotten me past that issue. However, it looks like there might be one other thing:
```
ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: error while mounting volume '/var/lib/docker/volumes/ddev-gsb-d8_nfsmount/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount :/Users/gmercer/Desktop/ddev/locals/gsb-3/public-website:/var/lib/docker/volumes/ddev-gsb-d8_nfsmount/_data, data: addr=192.168.65.2,hard,nolock: permission denied
Encountered errors while bringing up the project.' 
~/Desktop/ddev/locals/gsb-3/public-website (develop) $ 
```

Comment: This is caused by you needing to set up your nfs again. You should probably `sudo mv /etc/exports /etc/exports.bak` and then follow the instructions to set up nfs, https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/performance/#macos-nfs-setup

Comment: Yes... it was related to /etc/exports. I took a slightly different path - by adding my iTerm app to have 'full disk access' and then ran this command:
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drud/ddev/master/scripts/macos_ddev_nfs_setup.sh && chmod +x macos_ddev_nfs_setup.sh && ./macos_ddev_nfs_setup.sh

Thanks so much for all your help. I think we may have met one time at Drupal BadCamp. DDEV has been so nice for us to use. Thanks so much for that too. :)